# Ubuntu 14.04 + fglrx + google-chrome = glitches?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

if use --disable-gpu all is fine

Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90

fglrxinfo

display: :0  screen: 0

OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc

OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 5800 Series

OpenGL version string: 4.4.13283 Compatibility Profile Context 14.501.1003

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to confirm that disabling gpu support is working for me. If anyone is curious how to do this, you can simply go to Settings -> "Show advanced settings..." -> System and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"

This seems to have fixed the issue for me. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and fglrx from the Ubuntu repos on Chromium 45.0.2454.85.

Comment: It would be great if you could leave a little more information what the exact problem was. What kind of glitches did you experience?

Comment: I was experiencing the same type of artifacting as the screenshot left by user249654. This would generally occur after having a 6 or more tabs open and was usually triggered by scrolling on a somewhat complex page (with video, lots of ads, lots of DOM manipulation, etc). If I switched to a new tab and back again it sometimes went back to normal, but would continue until I got back down to fewer tabs open at the same time.